# How to Make a File Name appear as Form Text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, file

I am creating a text editor in VB.net with tabs and I am done so far. All I need is when the user saves the document or opens a document the name of the document shows up on the tab. I am using a separate tab control. I have it done but it shows the whole directory of the file. The only way to change the text on the tab is to change the text of the form I am using for the tab control to duplicate. So my code for when the user opens a file is:

```
Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        Dim alltext As String
        filename = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        alltext = File.ReadAllText(filename)
        FastColoredTextBox1.Text = alltext
        Me.Text = filename
    End Sub
```

But like I said it shows the whole directory of the file. Is there any way to make it just show the file name. The code for when the user saves the file has the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Me.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
```